# How to save CustomCell data in an Array?

Tags: ios, xcode

i have a customcell in my UITableView. This custom cell has a label and text box. when the user fills in the data (4-5 fields) and clicks the Save button. I want to save the Data he inputs.

How can i do that??

I just have around 5-6 fields max. It would be great if you could give some examples on how i can get this done.

Comment: Well there are several options depending on your specific scenario. How much data do you want to safe? Just a few strings or a lot of data? Please edit your question to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

One way: Save your data in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a data Structure of the data that he will fill, after save button is clicked. set these values to the data structure
Also you can use `NSMutableDictionary` key-value storage

Example: let say we have 4 `UITextFeilds` textFeild1, textFeild2, textFeild3, textFeild14

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic  = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dic addObject: textFeild1.text forValue: @"val1"];
[dic addObject: textFeild2.text forValue: @"val2"]; 
[dic addObject: textFeild3.text forValue: @"val3"];
[dic addObject: textFeild4.text forValue: @"val4"];

//Now you have the values and can retrieve them by: 
NSString *value1 = [dic  valueForKey:@"val1"];
```

Comment: Hossam - Can you please send me a piece of code and show me how its done. i am new to ios programing. that will be a great help

Answer (score 0):

Edit according to your comments:

In a case like this, Apple recommends to use the `Delegate-Pattern`. Basically, what you do is this:

```
@protocol FirstDataVCDelegate;

@interface FirstDataVC : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<FirstDataVCDelegate> delegate;

//...

@end

@protocol FirstDataVCDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)firstDataVC:(FirstDataVC *)dataVC didCollectData:(NSDictionary *)data;

@end


@interface RootVC: UIViewController<FirstDataVCDelegate>

//...

@end

@implementation RootVC

- (void)firstDataVC:(FirstDataVC *)dataVC didCollectData:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    NSString *name = [data valueForKey:@"name"];
    [self.completeData setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
}

@end
```

In this case `RootVC` would be the VC who wants to send the whole data. `FirstDataVC` is one of the VCs where the user inputs data.

Every VC that get userinput has to provide a protocol, that the `RootVC` implements.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html) is some more about delegation.

Comment: Thanks Tobi. But here i am using a Customcell and building the table rows automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry, but then I don't understand your question. Do you want to save the data the user inputs permanently to the device or do you just want to "collect" the data in a variable?

Comment: Sorry... i was not done yet and pressed enter... i don't have field name with me. Its an auto generated table. using Customcells

Comment: i want to collect data into a variable, like an array maybe. I have 4-5 View controller where the user inputs data. once he is done with all i need to send all the data to the server.

Comment: Ah ok, so your presenting these view controllers in a navigation controller and the user inputs a portion of the data in every vc?

Comment: Yes, you got it. how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pass the data back to the tableview? If so, you will have to save the info in a data structure and then pass it using a defined protocol.

Comment: I have 4-5 view controllers in a navigation controller... so the user may go back and forth. Each VC has around 5 input fields. I would like to hold the data that the user inputs in some array maybe and once he is done filling all the data then submit it to the server

Comment: I think Tobi answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tabTeamDetails dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customcellIdentifier"];

get UItextfeild and assign tag as below
   textbox.tag = indexpath.row; //used to refer particular textfiled
}
```

In save button action:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//for(i=0;i<noofrowsintableview;i++){
NSString *text = (NSString *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
[dic addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:text] forValue: i];
}
```